# Bind gridview selected row to DataTable in view-model

Tags: c#, mvvm, devexpress

I have a gridview in view and one property with a type is DataTable in viewmodel.
I want to bind the selected row in gridview to the property in view-model when the gridview row is click or get focused.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Tutorials](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114098/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Tutorials/Lesson-4-Data-Binding):

```
// Model
public class Model{
    // ...
}
// View Model
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel(){
        Entities = <... load entities here...>;
    }
    public IList<Model> Entities {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public virtual Model SelectedEntity {
        get;
        set;
    }
    protected void OnSelectedEntityChanged() {
        // do something
    }
}

// View
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
...
var fluent = mvvmContext.OfType<ViewModel>();
// bind the datasource
fluent.SetBinding(gridControl1, gControl => gControl.DataSource, x => x.Entities);
// bind the FocusedRowObject
fluent.WithEvent<ColumnView, FocusedRowObjectChangedEventArgs>(gridView1, "FocusedRowObjectChanged")
    .SetBinding(x => x.SelectedEntity,
        (args) => args.Row as Model,
        (gView, entity) => gView.FocusedRowHandle = gView.FindRow(entity));
```

PS. You can adapt the code above for any specific data-layer (e.g. the DataTable, but I believe the simple DTO list is a much better and maintainable choice).